# Export JasperReports query results

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export, resultset

in my Java project I have a lot of JasperReports reports with complex SQL queries, containing a lot of parameters. The reports are used to produce pdf documents containing the data returned by the query, grouped and formatted in various ways.

Now I also have the need to export directly the query result (e.g. a ResultSet, or a Map or a csv file, or similar...).
Is it possible to ask JasperReports to execute only the query and return results instead of rendering the pdf page?

(NOTE: it's not the same as choosing a csv output format to the report rendering, because this method tries to convert the report design to a csv file... Instead, I'd like only to "reuse" the query inside a report, also taking advantage of JR parameters management, etc...)

This is my Java code to produce a pdf document from a report:

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inStream);
JasperPrint jasperprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, conn);
JRAbstractExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.exportReport();
ByteArrayOutputStream os = (ByteArrayOutputStream) exporter.getParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM);
byte[] formattedReportBytes = os.toByteArray();
return formattedReportBytes;
```

I saw there's a class called `JRJdbcQueryExecuter` inside JasperReports...
Is it possible to call it directly instead of calling `fillReport`, in order to get the ResultSet of the executed SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use the JasperReports API for solving this task?

Comment: As I said before, I have a lot of reports which contains long sql queries (with many parameters) and produce complex pdf renderings, grouping data together, etc.. Now I also have to extract the database query results, without any processing, grouping, or rendering of any kind. It's like I manually copy the query from a report, I substitute all $P{} with actual values, I paste it inside an SQL client, execute it and extract it as a csv file. I'm looking for an automatic way to do this by code, taking advantage of JR parameters management and obtaining the query parsed and ready for execution...

Comment: And what is the purpose of this work? What will you do with returned ResultSet? Just interesting ...

Comment: I know I could copy my report queries into Java code, manually substitute all parameters with actual values using strings replace functions, etc... But in this way for every report I'd have to maintain two different queries, one hardcoded inside Java and the other included inside the report!

Comment: The purpose is to extract the query results as a csv or xls file, which is needed by some form of data processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to start with that this feels wrong and hacky, but it is possible, minus actually having JasperReports executing the query.

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inStream);

//this is the actual query in the report
JRQuery query = report.getMainDataSet().getQuery;

//once here you get the entire sql string, this will have any parameters replaced with 
//the '?' character
String queryString = query.getText();

//now start building your prepared statement, I am assuming you already have your
//connection in the conn variable
PrepararedStatment statement = con.prepareStatement(queryString);

//almost there, need to set the parameters
//the sql query is broke up into chunks inside the JRQuery. The chunks have types 
//that are  either text, parameter, or parameter clause. We care about parameter, 
//not sure what parameter clause would be to be honest
int index = 0; //this is the index to set the parameter at in the statement
for (JRQueryChunk chunk : query.getChunks()){
     if (chunk.getType() == JRQueryChunk .TYPE_PARAMETER){
         statement.setObject(index, params.get(chunk.getText()));
         index = index + 1;
     }
}
//then execute the query
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
```

**Note:** There is no error checking here, and you should add that. Also not sure if doing this is a great idea. It could be better to move the queries out of the reports and into your java code altogether. Then just pass in the ResultSet as a datasource and you are good to go.

Comment: Does not work. The queryString still includes parameters in the JR format (e.g. $P{PARAM_1} ), not parsed. 
I'm looking for a way to extract the final query as a String in order to manually execute it, or a way to intercept the moment when JR executes it and get the results back instead of continuing with the document rendering...

Comment: Are you sure about that, when I ran it the parameters where replaced with '?' characters. What about looping through the JRQueryChunks? You could rebuild the query and replace the parameters yourself with question marks.