# Jasper Reports. Testing SQL queries from JRXML templates

Tags: sql, unit-testing, jasper-reports

We have a task to implement several reports using pure JRXML (no custom Java code involved). The are two main reasons: reports can be generated using SQL queries only (no need for custom code) and they should be easy to deploy JasperReport server (no Java code = no need to install custom data sources and libraries).

However we still need to automate testing for these reports.
We decided to split testing of data retrieval (SQL query) and report rendering.

For testing SQL we would like to extract actual query from JRXML template for better future test maintenance.

We could manually copy report queries into our tests, manually substitute all parameters with actual values using strings replace functions, and so on. However in this case we would be forced manually maintain the same query in two places: our tests and our JRXML templates. And we would like to avoid it.

The problem with SQL queries retrieved from JRXML is that they still contain JasperReport-specific placeholders. Something like:

```
SELECT name, department FROM employees WHERE employee_id = $P{employeeId}
```

So far I have found something we could probably use (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789443/export-jasperreports-query-results)). However it still involves partial duplication of logic which JasperReports library implements (we need to duplicate logic for processing JRQueryChunks and adding parameter values to query).

Is there a better way to do it (I mean testing SQL from JRXML)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Jasper Server to deploy your reports, you can use the Jasper API to extract the deployed JRXML and strip the query and the parameters data types from there, replace the query parameters with some test params ($P{xxx} and $P!{xxx}) do your test and ready to go.

```
<parameter name="employeeId" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Integer(11)]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT name, department FROM employees 
                WHERE employee_id = $P{employeeId};]]>
</queryString>
```

If you are using default values for your parameters you can also use those in your tests, if you don't have a default value you at least have the data type and will be able to create a test value based on that.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I understood you right you are proposing extract parameters and SQL from JRXML (e.g. JasperDesign.getMainDataSet().getQuery()) and process this SQL replacing parameters placeholders, right? We have exactly the same idea. My question was: can avoid reinventing the wheel (parsing SQL query in our code) if Jasper already has this functionality?