# How to prepare resultset after extracting the query from the report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, resultset

I have a *JR* report file generated by *iReport4.5.0* and the query defined in the report file.

Currently I do the following to create the Jasper report:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportSrc, null, connection);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);
```

The issue is that I do not want to pass the connection to the `JasperFillManager` to fill the report, and would prefer to get the query from the report, execute the report, and pass the datasource to the `JasperFillManager`. Is this be possible?

**Note:-** Query will be part of Jasper report and I don't want write query in my java class.

---

I found the post [Export JasperReports query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789443/export-jasperreports-query-results) related to this problem.

I will try it and let everyone how much comfortable this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

While the linked question will work for what you are wanting to do, I do not recommend it. You are creating more work for yourself, and creating more places for things to go wrong. Essentially you are taking something that Jasper Reports has already implemented for you in `JRJdbcQueryExecuter`, and rewriting it.

If you don't trust, you can always go view the source code for yourself. Basically what I am saying  is to rethink what it is you are trying to accomplish and why before you go down this road. Maybe if you explained the why, it would make sense, I just can't think of a reason of the top of my head. But maybe there would be a better way to reach that goal.